# Does the sum of reciprocals of primes congruent to $1 \mod{4}$ diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $P$ be the set of primes $p$ greater than $3$ such that $p\equiv1 \pmod{4}$. Does the following sum converge or diverge?

$$
\sum_{p\in P}\frac{1}{p}
$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions

Comment: I have previously asked a [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/912852/131263) which you might find interesting (or find some of the answers to it interesting).

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415062

Answer (score 8):

This sum diverges (very, very, very slowly). In fact, so does the sum of the reciprocals of primes congruent to $3 \bmod 4$. Here's something amazing: asymptotically, these two sums diverge **at the exact same rate.**

We prove this using two pieces of information:

1. Integration by parts (with respect to Riemann-Stieltjes integration), and
2. An analytic statement of Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions. In particular, if $\pi_{a,b}(x)$ denotes the number of primes up to $X$ that are congruent to $a \bmod b$, and if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then
   $$ \pi_{a,b}(X) = \frac{1}{\varphi(b)} \frac{X}{\log X} + O(X e^{-c \sqrt{\log X}})$$
   for some absolute but unimportant constant $c > 0$.

Consider the sum
$$\begin{align}\sum_{\substack{p \equiv a \bmod b \\ p \leq X}} \frac{1}{p} &= \int_1^X \frac{1}{t} d\lfloor \pi_{a,b}(t) \rfloor \\
&= \frac{\pi_{a,b}(t)}{t} \bigg|_1^X + \int_1^X \frac{\pi_{a,b}(t)}{t^2} dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\varphi(b)} \frac{1}{\log X} + \int_1^X \frac{1}{\varphi(b)}\frac{1}{t \log t} dt + O \left( \int_1^X \frac{e^{-c \sqrt{\log t}}}{t}dt \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\varphi(b)} \log \log X + O(1),
\end{align}$$
where I've used that the integral and first term converge as $X \to \infty$ to some constant.

So the reciprocals of primes do diverge, even when restricted to congruence classes. And, remarkably, they diverge at the same rate asymptotically in any permissible congruence class. $\diamondsuit$

Comment: Nitpick: Fact #2 would more accurately be called the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions.  The analytic statement of Dirichlet's theorem is about the rate of divergence of $\sum_{p \equiv a \pmod b} p^{-s}$ as $s \to 1^+$, which also is enough to establish that the reciprocal sum diverges (and predates PNT).

Answer (score 2):

For any coprime $k,m$ the sum of the reciprocals of the primes $\equiv k\pmod m$ diverges.

Comment: I dare you to prove that.

Comment: @RaceBannon: It's easy given the Prime Number Theorem in arithmetic progressions -- or did you just mean that the PNT is hard to prove?

Comment: No, I was talking about the claim you posted. I would like to see a proof of your claim.

Comment: @RaceBannon: As I said, it's pretty easy to prove given the PNT in APs. This even gives the correct asymptotic -- $$\sum_{p\le x,\ p\equiv k\pmod m}\frac1p\approx\frac{\log\log x}{\varphi(m)}$$.

Comment: @RaceBannon, what does "dare" mean in this context? What sort of game is it? Anyway, this is standard.