# Riemann zeta function Euler product for primes equivalent to $3$ mod $4$

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, infinite-product

**Question:** can
$$
\zeta_1(s)
= \prod_{p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}
$$
be evaluated or written in terms of standard functions?

---

**Details:**

We can write the Riemann zeta function as
\begin{align*}
\zeta(s)
&= \prod_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1-2^{-s}}
\;\;
\underbrace{\prod_{p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}}_{\zeta_0(s)}
\quad
\underbrace{\prod_{p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}} \frac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}}_{\zeta_1(s)},
\end{align*}
so I'm asking for an evaluation of $\zeta_0(s)$ and $\zeta_1(s)$.

I encountered this while finding an expression for the probability that a "random" integer can be written as a sum of two squares, in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1414500/68107).
Since an integer is the sum of two squares iff it has an even number of each prime factor $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, the answer probability can be naturally written (after some work) as
$$
\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\zeta_1(2x)}{\zeta_1(x)}.
$$

Comment: What do you mean by "standard function"? For example, for me $\zeta$ is a standard function, is it for you?

Comment: @Wojowu I mean something very broad. Of course $\zeta$ function is standard. Any other function that has been defined in the literature or in a paper is standard.

Comment: See this MathOverflow question here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28000/what-are-the-analytic-properties-of-dirichlet-euler-products-restricted-to-arith

Comment: You might want to look up Dirichlet L functions.