# Modular Euler product?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

We know the Euler product.

$$\zeta (s)=\prod_{p}\frac{p^{s}}{p^{s}-1}$$

I wonder if there is formula or any kind of work for this kind of prime product below?

$$\prod_{p\equiv a \ (mod \ b)}\frac{p^{s}}{p^{s}-1}$$

Where $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: For $(a,b)=(1,2)$ the answer should be obvious. For $(a,b)=(1,4)$ and $(3,4)$ see [OEIS A$88539$](http://oeis.org/A088539) and [OEIS A$243379$](http://oeis.org/A243379). See also [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1415062).

Comment: and see the Dirichlet characters and L-function which are $$\prod_p \frac{1}{\displaystyle 1- p^{-s} e^{\textstyle \frac{2 i \pi}{b} \ln_{a,b}(p)}}$$
where $ \ln_{a,b}(p)$ is the discrete logarithm modulo $b$