# Sum of (only certain) prime reciprocicals

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

It is well known that

$$ \sum_{p\ is\ prime}\frac1{p}$$

diverges.

Is there a simple proof that

$$ \sum_{p\equiv 1\pmod 4}\frac1{p}$$

and

$$ \sum_{p\equiv 3\pmod 4}\frac1{p}$$

also diverge?

(p denotes prime numbers in both expressions above)

What I found so far are fairly complex considerations related to some more general issues, this must be simpler than that.

Comment: I think that maybe the formula $\pi_{n,a}(x)\sim \dfrac{1}{\varphi(n)}\text{Li}(x)$ will be a good place to start. For details see [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAAahUKEwjVkYeM8N_HAhXLGY4KHS7CC58&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPrime_number_theorem&usg=AFQjCNHYNEK9f2CSkswNeivg23wo4v_w9g).

Comment: Also see [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1400485/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-primes-congruent-to-1-mod4-diverge), especially **mixedmath**'s answer.

Comment: (stronger forms of) [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions) may help too (the primes are asymptotically evenly distributed between $1$ and $3$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an easy proof, see Proposition $5$ on page $4$ in the paper [Prime reciprocals and primes in arithmetic progressions](http://web.stanford.edu/~dalitt/exposnotes/primes1mod4.pdf) by Daniel Litt. The proof makes use of the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and its Euclidean norm, i.e., that $p=x^2+y^2$ for primes $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ The analytic part of the proof is quite simple. The idea can be also adapted to the case $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$, replacing the ring of Gaussian integers with the ring of Eisenstein integers, see remark $2$.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to prove that
$$\sum_{p>2}\frac{\chi(p)}{p}\tag{1}$$
is a convergent series to prove that both your series are divergent. Here $\chi(n)$ equals zero if $n$ is even, $1$ if $n=4k+1$ and $-1$ if $n=4k-1$. $\chi$ is a multiplicative function, and you may use the following consequence of the Euler's product
$$ \prod_{p>2}\left(1-\frac{\chi(p)}{p}\right)^{-1}=\sum_{n\equiv 1\!\!\pmod{2}}\frac{\chi(n)}{n}=\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^m}{2m+1}=\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4} \tag{2}$$
to prove that $(1)$ is converging. Notice that $(1)$ is essentially the logarithm of the LHS of $(2)$.