# Show divergence of an infinite product with terms containing congruence-restricted primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, infinite-product

> Show that $\displaystyle\prod_{p\equiv1(3)}\frac p{p-1}=\infty$ where $p$ is a prime number.

I know that $\displaystyle\prod_p\frac p{p-1}=\infty$. However, how can I show the above one?

Is there any inequality that implies $\displaystyle\prod_p\frac p{p-1}<\displaystyle\prod_{p\equiv1(3)} \frac p{p-1}$?

Otherwise, can you help me to solve it?

Comment: I think some strong form of Dirichlet's theorem (on primes in arithmetic progressions) is necessary here. I don't know whether this statement can be proven without it.

Comment: Yah..I think so, Dirichlet's L-series is required for some sort of contradiction.

Comment: You don't use it to get a contradiction. You can show that e.g. the sum $\sum_{p\equiv 1\pmod 3}\frac{1}{p}$ diverges and go from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need two parts. The first part is
$$\prod_{p\equiv1\bmod3}\frac p{p-1}=\prod_{p\equiv1\bmod6}\left(1+\frac1{p-1}\right)\ge\prod_{p\equiv1\bmod6}\left(1+\frac1p\right)\ge1+\sum_{p\equiv1\bmod6}\frac1p$$
The second part is proving the last infinite sum diverges. For one such proof, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1400798/357390).

Therefore the original infinite product diverges.

Comment: Is there a convention that $\infty>\infty$ in number theory?

Comment: @tomasz Nah, this is just series comparison.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\geq$ then?

Comment: @tomasz Doesn't matter either way...