# Is the series $\sum 1/p$ in which p is prime converges?

Tags: analysis, number-theory

Is the series $\sum 1/p$ in which p is prime converges? I remembered there's some theorem about this. THank you

Comment: As an interesting exercise, try to come up with an infinite subset of primes, such that the sum of the reciprocal elements of that subset converges. You might be surprised of how non-trivial this task is.

Comment: @barakmanos: $a_0=2$ and $a_n={}$smallest prime${} \ge 2a_{n-1}$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: What???

Comment: It diverges because [$\log \zeta(s) = \sum_p p^{-s} +  \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product) where the second series converges for $Re(s) > 1/2$, and $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$ therefore $\lim_{s \to 1^+} \sum_p p^{-s} = + \infty$ so $\sum_p p^{-1}$ cannot converge (series of positive terms)

Comment: @barakmanos: That generates an infinite sequence of primes such that the sum of their reciprocals converges.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Not sure I understand the term "generates" in this context (I see only two elements here - $a_0$ and $a_1$).

Comment: @barakmanos $\sum_n \frac{1}{p_{n^2}}$ converges without problems, of course it is not easy to find if $q \in \{ p_{n^2}\}$ so maybe that's what you meant

Comment: @user1952009: Let alone proving this claim.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Hahaha. You've used the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}$... nice :)

Comment: @HenningMakholm: I posted that [as a question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/912852/131263) quite a while ago. The best answer there is somewhat similar to yours now that I think about it, but if you think it's different enough then please feel free to add it there...

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. You can consider the function $$ P(z)=\sum_{p=prime}\frac{1}{p^z}$$  and you can show that this series converges for $\Re(z)>1$ . One can also prove that the line $\Re(z)=0 $ is a natural boundary for the function we defined eariler, which means that $P(z)$ has no analytic continuation on the left half plane.