# Convergence of the sum of reciprocals of a subset of primes involving $\pi$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Let $p_i$ denote the $i^{\rm th}$ prime number, and let $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denote the greatest integer smaller than or equal to $x$. Then does the sum defined by:

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_{\lfloor\pi n\rfloor}}
$$

converge?

Computing the partial sum up to $n=3\times10^7$ yields a value of about $\approx 0.890694\ldots$, and Wolfram Alpha gives the following plot, suggesting that the sum might be convergent:

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

Note that Wolfram **does not** explicitly state that the sum is non-convergent, as it does for instance in the case $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_{2n}}$.

Comment: It surely diverges. Matijasevic said, the sum over all known primes $p$ of $1/p$ is less than 5 – and it always will be. The divergence may be very slow, but it is certain.

Comment: But we know that sums of reciprocals of certain subsets of primes can converge, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1875520/does-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-this-subset-of-the-primes-converge and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912852/define-an-infinite-subset-of-primes-such-that-the-sum-of-reciprocals-converges

Comment: Sure, but as you say, $\sum p_{2n}^{-1}$ diverges, and so do $\sum p_{3n}^{-1}$ and $\sum p_{4n}^{-1}$ and so on, and your sum is in that family.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was thinking the same thing. What intrigued me is that Wolfram does not say they diverge, while for $\sum p_{2n}^{-1}$ it does

Comment: I don't know what Wolfram says, since you haven't told us where to find it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Simply put `sum 1/Prime[floor(pi*n)], for n=1 to infinity` into https://www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: And if you put the same for $2n$ into alpha, it explicitly tells you the sum diverges? I guess alpha is clever, but not quite clever enough.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it says "sum does not converge": `https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1%2FPrime%5B2*n%5D,+for+n%3D1+to+infinity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\lfloor \pi n \rfloor \leq 4n$. It is therefore sufficient to show the divergence of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_{4n}}$$
Assume it does converge. Note that
$$\frac{1}{p_{4n+k}} \leq \frac{1}{p_{4n}}$$
for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Thus, the sum 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_{4n+k}}$$ converges for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence
$$\infty > \sum_{k=0}^3 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{p_{4n+k}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{3}\frac{1}{p_{4n+k}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p_n}$$
But the right hand sum diverges.

This is an instance of a more general fact which is not related to prime numbers:
If a sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$$
with $a_0 \geq a_1 \geq .. $ an all $a_n \geq 0$ diverges, then for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, the sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{kn}$$
diverges. The proof is the same as above.

Comment: I disagree with the first line in your answer. The sequence $p_{\lfloor\pi n\rfloor}$ starts with: $5,13,23,37,47$, while $p_{4n}$ starts with: $7,19,37,53,71$. The sum of their reciprocals cannot therefore be compared.

Comment: Maybe I am confused. But, as you write, $p_{\lfloor \pi n\rfloor} \leq p_{4n}$, therefore $(p_{4n})^{-1} \leq (p_{\lfloor \pi n\rfloor})^{-1}$.

Comment: I agree with that. However, I do not with the statement "*It is therefore sufficient to show the divergence of $\sum p_{4n}^{-1}$*", since we are talking about *indices* of prime numbers, not the prime numbers themselves. Therefore the sequences are completely different, and the reciprocals also.

Comment: But we have $\sum p_{4n}^{-1} \leq \sum p_{\lfloor \pi n \rfloor}^{-1}$. Divergence follows then by the comparision test for series with non-negative summands.

Comment: Did you mean $\sum p_{4n}^{-1} \geq \sum p_{\lfloor \pi n\rfloor}^{-1}$? Also, how can you compare two series with completely different terms? It might be that all the terms of one are smaller than all the terms of the other, but this does not mean that if one diverges, so does the other...

Comment: As I worte above, $p_{4n}^{-1} \leq p_{\lfloor \pi n\rfloor}^{-1}$. And this holds for all(!) $n$. This implies $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_{4n}^{-1} \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} p_{\lfloor \pi n \rfloor}^{-1}$.

Comment: And: For two series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$ with $0 \leq a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n$, we have  $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$. Thus divergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n$ implies divergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$. (That is the comparison test!) To understand my argument from above, set $a_n=p_{4n}^{-1}$ and $b_n=p_{\lfloor \pi n \rfloor}^{-1}$.

Comment: If that were true all series would diverge, because you can always find a $b_n$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n$

Comment: The last assertion in the answer is wrong, an assumption like monotonicity of the sequence $(a_n)$ is required. Otherwise, consider $a_n = n^{-2 - (-1)^n}$, then $\sum a_{kn}$ converges for even $k$.

Comment: @Pickle You misunderstand. The sequence $(b_n)$ is given, and its convergence or divergence shall be determined. If you can find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that for all $n$ you have $0 \leqslant a_n \leqslant b_n$, and such that $\sum a_n$ diverges, then you conclude that $\sum b_n$ diverges too. In the situation of this question, $b_n = p_{\lfloor \pi n\rfloor}$, and $a_n = p_{4n}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for your remark! I edit my answer. Also, your counterexample is quite nice.

Comment: even though your argument still holds for $p_{3n}^{-1}$ that is diverge sum, actually and $p_{c n}^{-1}$ is diverge sum given that $c>0$ and constant.

Comment: easier to prove by PNT, which imply that $p_n > n \ln n$ so $\frac{1}{\pi n \ln(\pi n)}$ is obviously diverges.